# Git Bash switching version in python

Tags: python, bash, git, python-2.7, git-bash

I have installed Python27 already in my C: drive. I have a code written in Python2.7.x and when I type the statement in Git Bash command line-

```
python --version
```

it gives me

```
3.8.1
```

How do I run the Python2.7.x script named first.py which is in the following directory

```
C:/Python27/m1/m1/first.py
```

Comment: Can `py -2` and `py -3` work in your Git Bash?

Comment: @ElpieKay I opened git bash and typed in py -2 but the cursor goes to next line without an output

Comment: My fault. Kill the terminal and reopen one. Try `winpty py -2` and `winpty py -3`. If it works, add `alias py='winpty py'` to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks for that. It does work and take me to python 2.7.18. How do I add alias py='winpty py' to ~/.bashrc

Comment: @LGEYH : How about using a text editor? That's what they are made for.

Comment: @LGEYH Run `echo "alias py='winpty py'" >> ~/.bashrc`. You can also run `ls -l ~/.bashrc` first to see its absolute path and then use an editor to open and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what version of python you have installed by

```
py -0
```

You can use to execute your script in python 2

```
winpty py -2 <your_file>
```

If you python 3

```
winpty py -3 <your_file>
```

If you have more than one python 3 installed on your machine (3.8, 3.9) and you want to test you file in python 3.9

```
winpty py -3.9 <your_file>
```

You can add alias command for `winpty py` by adding alias to `.bashrc` file

```
alias py='winpty py'
```

and now instead of typing `winpty py` use `py` instead